# Interpolated string not escaping properly

Tags: c#, string, string-interpolation

I have the following bit of code:

```
public static string GetDomainRole(string role)
{
    return $"{Startup.Configuration["Domain:Name"]}\\{role}";
}
```

Where

```
Startup.Configuration["Domain:Name"] = "MyDomain"
role = "SomeDomainRole"
```

And neither have anything other than `a -> z, A -> Z, _` for their characters.

If I remove the first `\`, then I get an error saying:

> A '{' may only be escaped by doubling '{{' in an interpolated string

The problem is, my resultant string from `GetDomainRole(...)` is:

```
MyDomain\\SomeDomainRole
```

With the double `\\`. This obviously does not match my domain role `MyDomain\SomeDomainRole`.

I'm sure I'm missing something really small here, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get rid of the double `\\`.

**EDIT**

Appears I just needed to adjust my search terms. This is a duplicate of [How to use escape characters with string interpolation in C# 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31333096/how-to-use-escape-characters-with-string-interpolation-in-c-sharp-6)

Comment: How are you determining that the return value of `GetDomainRole` contains two backslashes?  If you're viewing it in the debugger it's very possible that the debugger is showing you the *escaped* version of the string, so it's showing the backslash as escaped.

Comment: @Kyle you are correct. It was. Problem was *when* I was inspecting the value...