# How to use string interpolation and verbatim string together to create a JSON string literal?

Tags: c#, .net, string, string-interpolation, verbatim-string

I'm trying to create a string literal representing an array of JSON objects so I thought of using string interpolation feature as shown in the code below:

```
    public static void MyMethod(string abc, int pqr)
    {
        string p = $"[{{\"Key\":\"{abc}\",\"Value\": {pqr}  }}]";
    }
```

Now I thought of using verbatim string so that I don't have to escape double quotes using backslashes. So I came to know through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32508711/465053) answer that verbatim string and string interpolation can be used together. So I changed my code as below:

```
public static void MyMethod(string abc, int pqr)
{
    string p = $@"[{{"Key":"{abc}","Value": {pqr} }}]";
}
```

But it fails to compile. Can anyone help me if there is anything wrong in my usage or it will *not* be possible to escape double quotes in such a case using string verbatim feature of C#?

Comment: Verbatim strings require that you escape double quotes by doubling them up. `$@"[{{""Key"":""{abc}"",""Value"": {pqr} }}]"` will work, but this is hardly more readable. Consider using a JSON serializer to avoid string wetwork.

Comment: @RBT even assuming you really really don't want to use a JSON serializer I'd avoid to build string this way, format string quickly becomes absolutely unreadable and error-prone. In this case maybe `String.Format()` will help and if you write few more functions then you will have a nice short readable code snippet (`QuoteJsonString()`, `ConvertToJsonKeyValuePair()` and one line LINQ to concat them...)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The best way is to use **JSON serializers** as they have in-built handling related to escape characters and other things. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6201529/5417658).

However, if we want to go through this path only to create the JSON string manually, then it can be solved as follows by changing the inner double quotes to single quotes :

```
public static string MyMethod(string abc, int pqr)
{
   string p = $@"[{{'Key':'{ abc}','Value': {pqr} }}]";
   return p;
}
```

Comment: This is not valid JSON. Single quotes are valid Javascript, but not JSON.

Comment: You can use double quotes to escape the quotes, ie @" { ""key"": ""value"" } "

However, despite the manual indicating that you can combine $@ for an interpolated verbatim string, VSCode is telling me that doing so is an error. Not sure what the exactly correct syntax is to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

you can create dictionary and serialize it to json using Json.NET does this.

```
Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
values.Add("key1", "value1");
values.Add("key2", "value2");

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);
// {
//   "key1": "value1",
//   "key2": "value2"
// }
```

you can see here more detail : http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm

Comment: I'm going to leverage this piece of code in a method which gets called from custom action of installshield. Adding a dependency on JSON.NET  dll in my C# project will invite adding a dependency on this dll in the installshield project as well. This is an explicit work which is a fair amount of overhead just to fix this one line of code on C# side if at all it can be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with everyone else that building it from strings is a bad idea.
I also understand that you don't want to include an extra dependency.

Here's a bit of code I wrote previously to convert a Dictionary to a JSON string. It's pretty basic, only accepts string types, and doesn't escape quote marks in any of the names/values, but that can be done fairly easily.

If you're trying to serialize a large JSON string from basic types, this is the way I'd recommend to do it. It'll help you stay sane.

```
private static string DictToJson(Dictionary<string, string> Dict)
{
    var json = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var Key in Dict.Keys)
    {
        if (json.Length != 0)
            json = json.Append(",\n");

        json.AppendFormat("\"{0}\" : \"{1}\"", Key, Dict[Key]);
    }
    return "{" + json.ToString() + "}";
}
```

Comment: In my JSON data I can also have int, date values. You are taking every value as string.