# Can't use literal curly braces around interpolated string

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I have been reading [this SO post carefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31333096/how-to-use-escape-characters-with-string-interpolation-in-c-sharp-6/32508711), trying to put curly brace literals around my interpolated strings.

```
string testString = "foo";
string testResult1 = $"{testString}"; // result = "foo" as expected
string testResult2 = $"{{testString}}"; // result = "{testString}" - UH OH
```

My expected result for `testResult2` is "**{foo}**". I have tried escaping the outer curlies with backslash, but that doesn't work, and I didn't expect it to. How can I put literal curly braces around an interpolated string variable? A more accurate example is this:

```
string testResult3 = $"I want to eat some {{testString}} please.";
```

> Expected: "I want to eat some {foo} please."
>
> Actual: "I want to eat some {testString} please."

How can I make this work? (I also tried `@` between `$` and `"`, but no joy.)

Comment: Two curly braces evaluate to a literal curly brace.  Therefore you need three curly braces: `string testResult2 = $"{{{testString}}}";` to produce `{foo}`.

Comment: @ChrisR.Timmons that's more suited for an answer :)

Comment: We have a winner...Chris, pls post your answer as such.

Answer (score 6):

From [Chris R. Timmons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116198/chris-r-timmons):

Two curly braces evaluate to a literal curly brace. Therefore you need three curly braces:

```
string testResult2 = $"{{{testString}}}";
```

...to produce `{foo}`.