# C# mutiline code string interpolation not working

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to add some code to a code string like this

```cs
        public static string Compile(string code)
        {
            Write("compiler called.");
/////////////Below is the string I want to interpolate//////////////
            
            string codeToCompile = $@"
            using System;

            namespace RoslynCompileSample
            {
                public class Writer
                {
                    public string Write()
                    {
                        
                        {code}
                    }
                }
            }";
///////////////// Other Codes...//////////////////////////
```

I've tried to use `$@` but still not recognized as a string:[image]

Comment: Oh sorry that was a typo, because there's no `code` variable, the `code`' is method's parameter, let me fix the question.

Comment: Why are you using an interpolated string? You don't appear to need interpolation for this string and the fact that C# contains { } naturally as part of its scoping means it breaks the interpolation you have no need for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things to mention here:

1. Assignment of `code` is done incorrectly
2. You have to escape the `{` and `}` characters within the interpolated string (Read the [special characters section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated#special-characters) of the docs)
   (if you want to use a `"` too (in an [verbatim string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) with `@`, you have also double it to `""` to get one), e.g. `string code = @"Console.WriteLine(""Helloworld"");";`

```
string code = "Console.WriteLine(\"Helloworld\");";
string codeToCompile = $@"using System;

namespace RoslynCompileSample
{{
    public class Writer
    {{
        public string Write()
        {{
            var code = {code}
        }}
    }}
}}";
```

Comment: See also [How to use escape characters with string interpolation in C# 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31333096/1043380)